# How do you uninstall Pathogen for vim?

Tags: macos, vim, plugins, osx-mavericks, pathogen

I installed `NERDTree` with `Pathogen`, then was not successful in installing `snipMate` plugin. This is my 3rd day now and I'm giving up on pathogen. I'm trying vundle. Questions:

1. Do I have to uninstall pathogen? If yes, how? Step by step method please since I'm new to Mac(Osx 10.9) and coding.
2. Do I have to delete `.vim/autoload` directory since it's part of pathogen?

Comment: As for 2. Do you have to No. Should you doesn't matter. If its empty it doesn't really need to be there. But it is not part of pathogen. It is a special directory used by vim to load functions when needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to uninstall it,

- delete `~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim`,
- delete the lines you have added to `~/.vimrc`.

Also, see [this guide I wrote about Pathogen](https://gist.github.com/romainl/9970697).

Comment: Hahaha. Exactly what I'm thinking. Anyways, I was able to install snipMate and a bunch more plugins using `Vundle` and in the process of checking off your steps 1 & 2. Also working on step 3. But that's gonna take a while - thanks.

Comment: Can we be a bit nicer here, @romainl? Btw, while you're being so pedantic you probably should have also been accurate regarding how to *remove* files (via `rm`) instead of via delete in a *nix shell...

Comment: @TimErickson, 1. The OP can delete files in anyway he choses, 2, my answer made him/her laugh and solved is problem.